# Auto creating table if not existing is causing error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to create following table . query works in phpmyadmin but doesn't work in php script. pls point out mistake in my code. Thank You

```
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_sid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table portal created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the 
right syntax to use near '`id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`message_sid` varchar(255) NOT NULL' at line 2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly with the mysql db. Let me check with MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by checking if table exists in php, on false create a new table
creating table would be best to export an already existing one with phpmyadmin and then just use it as query syntax

Comment: I generated this query from phpmyadmin.and this query work in php my admin sql field but not working in php scrip.

Comment: Somehow mine one generates `id` int(11) instead of 255 try that

Answer (score -1):

Take the single quotes off of your table and row names

also if you make the id a primary key auto-increment, do not make it not null, this will cause a error.

I am unsure why the down votes....

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS portal ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
message_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
number VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
message text NOT NULL, 
created_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL )ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This will work